# How to force scroll bars to be always visible in an AIR mobile app?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am trying to "port" a desktop air app to a mobile one. I need the scroll bars to be always visible so that the user knows that there is more information. How do I force scroll bars to be always visible like the desktop version?
In terms of components in the application, i have a spark List, spark Image and spark DropDownList where i would like the scrollbars to remain visible always.

Googling brings up  "http://flexponential.com/2011/07/30/controlling-scroll-bar-visibility-in-a-mobile-scroller/".

I am not an expert so not sure how the sample project in the above link is useful for me.

If it is of any help i am using Adobe AIR sdk 3.1. (I can upgrade if helps solving the problem else would like to stick to it for now. )

Any pointers / help from experts out there?

Thank you for taking time out to read this.

Comment: not sure there's many mobile platform that would accept AIR 3.1. For sure your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: @BotMaster how does that relate to his question? what makes you think he wants to put it in the app store? maybe it's an app for one specific client, so neither he, the client or the apple will care.

Comment: It does not relate to the question that's why it's posted in comments. Sure it's possible it's purposely made that way with a now mobile incompatible SDK but in case it's not I thought I would clear that out right away. In the worst case that is an irrelevant comment, in the best case I save that guy hours of trouble.

Comment: @BotMaster: The app is not meant for apple. The target platform is android. I am willing to upgrade the sdk if solves the issue i am facing.

Comment: "I am willing to upgrade the sdk if solves the issue i am facing" np suit yourself. The max Android version you can target is 3.2 and the number of AIR feature you'll be missing is too long to list here and not mentioning how slow your app is gonna be in comparison to what's possible with the latest AIR sdks but that's your decision.

Comment: @Botmaster: Are you suggesting that by upgrading to a higher version of air sdk will solve my problem?

Comment: At no point I'm saying that.